# Shortening Code - Multiple inputs/video for one function

Tags: javascript, video, input, click

I want to shorten my code since the I am repeating the same function for each button and video, but I get lost when trying to understand how to make things run through the same function when clicked. Right now I am using onclick in HTML, but I would like for the code to use an eventListener as well and Javascript only.

I have tried using for loops for the button and video, but I will admit that I do not know what exactly it is that I'm doing.

```
<script>

    // function for "stop"
    var vid1 = document.getElementById("video1");
        vid1.style.display = "none";
    var img1 = document.getElementById("button1");

        function vidToggle1() {
            img1.style.display = "none";
            vid1.style.display = "block";
            vid1.play();
        }
        vid1.onended = function() {
            vid1.style.display = "none";
            img1.style.display = "block";
        }

    // function for "more"
    var vid2 = document.getElementById("video2");
        vid2.style.display = "none";
    var img2 = document.getElementById("button2");

        function vidToggle2() {
            img2.style.display = "none";
            vid2.style.display = "block";
            vid2.play();
        }
        vid2.onended = function() {
            vid2.style.display = "none";
            img2.style.display = "block";
        }

</script>
```

Right now it the code does what I want, but I just want it shorter. The code is supposed to display the input image and when clicked, it is supposed to play the video clip assigned to that input, then video is to go back to the initial image upon finished playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass elements as function parameters. For example:

```
function playVideo(vid, img) {
  img.style.display = "none";
  vid.style.display = "block";
  vid.play();

  vid.onended = function() {
    vid.style.display = "none";
    img.style.display = "block";
    vid.onended = undefined
  }
}


var vid1 = document.getElementById("video1");
vid1.style.display = "none";
var img1 = document.getElementById("button1");

var vid2 = document.getElementById("video2");
vid2.style.display = "none";
var img2 = document.getElementById("button2");
```

Then to play the first video you can call `playVideo(vid1, img1)`, and for the second `playVideo(vid2, img2)`.

If you have any questions feel free to ask me in the comments.

Comment: I am still having trouble. Now all my code does is display both inputs and their video, and doesn't do anything when played. I used an addEventListener to call the function.

Comment: Did you have this problem before? Lemme see if I missed something

Comment: I got it to work, thank you. Now, how would I make this look with an eventListener instead of an onclick in the HTML? I have tried the following: document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", playVideo(img1, vid1));

Comment: @Aldair That way it'll call playVideo immediately, then set the return value of that to be called on the event listener. Instead, it should take a function, for example `document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", () => playVideo(img1, vid1));`. Are you familiar with arrow function syntax?

Comment: ahh, I have seen them once but the bootcamp that I am learning from has not taught that. They seem easier to grasp than traditional functions, but I have not messed with them much.

Comment: @Aldair `() => doSomething()` and `() => { doSomething() }` are equivalent to `function() { doSomething() }`.

Comment: hey, you helped me out a bit ago on this. I went back to this same project to update it a bit with arrow functions. I am running into an issue. I have the js code running well on the first 8 buttons for my first html page, but then I try using the same js code for other html pages and for some reason it is not working. Everything is linked, just not reacting like my first working html page.

Comment: Hey @Aldair! Are you sure that the ids of the HTML elements on the new page are the same as in the JavaScript code? It's kinda hard to help you without seeing the code. Try adding a `console.log` statement at the beginning of the `playVideo` function to see if it's even being called.

Comment: I just gave each page its own js file and it works, but I still don't get why it wasn't working initially, all the id names matched. Also, is it good stackoverflow etiquette to keep asking about different things on the same post? I have another question about the same project I am working on.

Comment: @Aldair if it's an unrelated question, yeah, it's good etiquette to make a new post